# VirtualBox. Fedora 11 freezes when boot

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora11

I have Fedora 11 installed on VirtualBox. By accident some files in /var directory were damaged or removed(I don't know what exactly). Now when trying to run Fedora, it goes untill choosing the user and freezes. No reaction at mouse and keyboard clicks. Does anyone have any suppositions how to run it, or at least how to retrieve files from virtual machine? I booted it to the terminal where I updated all what is possible - gnome, etc...But still no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to know what happened without knowing what got removed. However, a great way to get your files out is using `scp`. Good examples for this can be found [here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

Alternatively, if you've installed the Virtualbox Guest Additions you can use a USB drive to retrieve your files. There's a pretty good tutorial on how to get your USB drive working on VBox [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31726/mount-usb-devices-in-virtualbox-with-ubuntu/).

If you want my best guess as to what's wrong, something in your /var relating to your GUI got removed, as from what I understand you can still boot to your command line. My suggestion would be to get what you need off the machine using the above tools and get a fresh install.

Comment: but is it possible to transfer files through filezilla or somethig like that, if I am booted in command line mode?

Comment: Filezilla is just an ftp client. So you can also use ftp or sftp to transfer over the files. Here's a good [tutorial](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/classes/tutorials/ftp/ftp.html)